# htaccess mod_rewrite:

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**hey guys,**
I have `mypage.com/user-login.php?action=register` and I want to be able to call `mypage.com/register` to see the same result.

What would a mod_rewrite rule for that look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register$ user-login.php?action=register
```

Comment: If you wanted to avoid typing "register" twice, you could capture the pattern and use a backreference: `RewriteRule ^(register)$ user-login.php?action=$1`.